# Complete localization of Kendo UI widgets

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, localization, kendo-grid

I've been trying to implement a complete localization in the Kendo UI widgets using the resource files but not able to get any specific result.

What I want is to localize each and every messages of the widgets. Can anybody suggest how to implement this using resource files?

Is there any difference in implementing localization in Kendo Grid's JQuery syntax and razor syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Option 1 - Custom Resource File**

You can inject your own messages into the Kendo widgets. If your resources are named Resources.resx you can set the localization messages like this:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid( {
    filterable: {
        messages: {
            info: "@Resources.FilterInfo",
            filter: "@Resources.Filter" 
        }
    }
});
```

You can only do this in your razor files.

**Option 2 - Messages File**

You can use the messages files to automatically localize your Kendo UI, as shown [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/globalization#localized-user-interface).

If the CurrentUICulture is set (from code or web.config) Telerik UI for ASP.NET MVC will use localized user interface messages.

Telerik UI for ASP.NET MVC comes with localized messages for the following cultures:

- bg-BG - Bulgarian (Bulgaria)
- da-DK - Danish (Denmark)
- de-DE - German (Germany)
- es-ES - Spanish (Spain)
- en-US - English (US)
- fr-FR - French (French)
- nl-NL - Dutch (Netherlands)
- pl-PL - Polish (Poland)
- pt-BR - Portuguese (Brazil)
- pt-PT - Portuguese (Portugal)
- ro-RO - Romanian (Romania)
- ru-RU - Russian (Russia)
- sv-SE - Swedish (Sweden)
- uk-UA - Ukrainian (Ukraine)
- zh-CN - Chinese (PRC)

If the CurrentUICulture is not supported the default "en-US" will be used.

In this case you can create your own messages file and reference it in your code, as shown [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/globalization#adding-new-localizations).

Comment: hi vash,first of all thanx for the reply. but i am unlucky in terms coz i have used these js files but  i was not able to find any js file for ms-MY..this is what my basic requirement is. and also i have used resource files shared by telerik with unknowing success, but still confused how those files worked for me..... i want to use them in my different project but now the same logic is not working for me.